# Changing order of domain properties

Tags: visual-studio, dsl

When designing a DSL with the Microsoft DSL Toolkit, how do you change the order of a Domain Property of a Domain class. I have a `ClassA` with domain properties `Name` and `IsOptional` but I would want the `IsOptional` to be the first domain property for this domain class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require that the DomainClass is contained within a CompartmentShape object.

The following article neatly describes how to achieve this:
[DSL Drag Drop Compartment Shape Ordering](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3ecb9fe-7627-4368-8434-148cb62442dc/how-to-drag-drop-compartment-shape-ordering?forum=dslvsarchx)